# Conexión a una BD Mongo hospedada en mlab.com desde C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Buenas tardes:

Estoy realizando un proyecto en C# el cuál debe conectarse con una BD MongoDb, dicha BD debe estar hospedada en mlab.com. El problema es que hice la aplicación y la probaba con localhost, ahora intenté pegar la URL del servidor mlab y la aplicación sigue almacenando los datos en la BD que estaba en localHost, no en el servidor en mlab.com aún y cuando en el String de conexión tengo la dirección del servidor que mlab da. ¿Alguien sabe qué podrá ser?

La conexión la hago así:

> MongoClient mc = new
>   MongoClient("mongodb://user:password@servidor:puerto/baseDatos");
>
> MongoServer ms = mc.GetServer();
>
> MongoDatabase db = ms.GetDatabase("baseDatos");
>
> MongoCollection usuarioCollection = db.GetCollection("users");
>
> usuarioCollection.Insert(usuario);
>
> Console.ReadLine();

Como se puede ver, hago todo para que los datos se vayan a almacenar en mlab, pero por alguna extraña razón, se guardan en localhost. Perdón, soy completamente nuevo con MongoDB

¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: seguro no estas apuntando a la base correcta.. pero sin ver lo que estas haciendo va a ser muy dificil ayudarte. Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Muchas gracias, he tomado tu consejo y he editado la consulta. Puse el código de la conexión. Muchas gracias!